# What do midget goliaths count as for Badass Rank?

Tags: borderlands-2

In *Borderlands 2*, there are midgets, and there are goliaths. These two enemies have badass rank missions for killing them. There are also midget goliaths. What do these count for? Just midgets? Just goliaths? Both at the same time? Neither?

Comment: Maybe a midget + a Goliath?

Comment: @Ginge I guess so, but need a real test to ensure this.

Comment: You can do a controlled test, note what your badass rank is before and after you kill one of them, and then see the difference.

Comment: Note that this interaction is not unique to goliaths. There are midget rats, nomads, psychos, etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Borderlands Wiki](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Midget_Goliath), midget goliaths are a variant of goliaths, just as there are midget versions of other entities in Borderlands 2. Midget goliaths count as goliaths for badass rank.